# Rewriting squareroot function in the form (a-b)(a+b)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, factoring

[image]

I have this function and I'm trying to write a program to compute it as n approaches 100. The problem is it overflows once it reaches around 50. The hint to solving this question is to rewrite the part inside the parentheses (sqrt(1+2^-n*Xn) - 1) to (a-b)(a+b), but I'm having trouble thinking of how to do that.

Comment: Multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{1+2^{-n}x_n}+1$. On top we get something nice.

Comment: In the language C#, the max value that could be stored in an integer is $9,223,372,036,854,775,807$, that is 2 to the power 63. As a result, you need to re-write the expression with much reduced powers of 2, somehow...

Comment: What is $x_0$? It would help to spare us the calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $(a+b)(a-b)$ is $a^2 - b^2$, so perhaps you treat the two terms as $a^2$ and $b^2$ to get:

$$x_{n+1} = 2^{n+1}((1+2^{-n}x_n)^{1/4} + 1)((1+2^{-n}x_n)^{1/4} - 1)$$

Maybe this helps?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, assume $x>0$:

$$\sqrt x-1= (x^{1/4})^2-1=(x^{1/4} -1)(x^{1/4}+1). $$

But I am not sure that it will be easier now.